# If $f$ and $g$ are harmonic on the complex plane and if $f(x) = g(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, does $f(z) = g(z)$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ and $g$ are harmonic on the complex plane and
if $f(x) = g(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, does $f(z) = g(z)$ for all 
$z\in\mathbb{C}$?

I can see that if $f$ and $g$ were entire then by the identity theorem we would have $f=g$. Thus, I tried to work with two entire functions $F=f+if_2$ and $G=g+ig_2$ in order to argue similarly but that wasn't successful.

Comment: Complex functions $z$ and $\overline{z}$ are both harmonic, right?

Comment: That's really neat and simple, thank you! I thought it was true and didn't spend time looking for counterexamples...